# AngularJS: Limit selections from dropdown list (using angularMultipleSelect)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm stuck on this issue:  I'm trying to limit the number of selections a user can make from an available dropdown selection list.  The list is drawn from a database, so its not a hard-coded option list. I'm currently using angularMultipleSelect, its works fine expect for this requirement.

If the user exceeds the maximum selections, I want to set the field to invalid, so that the user cannot save the form. The user should then remove one or more of the selections, until the valid selections are made, then the field should reset to valid.  I've tried using:

- after-select-item (a directive available with angularMultipleSelect)
- ng-change
- custom validation directive

None of these work.  I can get ng-change & custom validation directive to work on other input fields in the same form, but not on the 'multiple-autocomplete' tag.  Nothing is triggered when the user makes selections from the dropdown list.

Here is a simple sample of the code used with after-select-item method.  I'm trying to limit the user to 3 or less selections from the available options in the 'cats' array.

HTML:

`<multiple-autocomplete 
                        ng-model="selectedCats" 
                        name="selectedCats" 
                        object-property="name"
                        after-select-item="afterSelectItem" 
                        required
                        suggestions-arr="cats">
</multiple-autocomplete>`

Controller.js:

```
$scope.afterSelectItem = function(selectedCats) {
    var catLength = $scope.selectedCats.length;        
    var valid = (catLength <= 3);
    $scope.myStoryForm.selectedCats.$setValidity("maxLength", valid);
 };
```

Again, nothing gets triggered in this controller when selections are been made (checked at console).

Is there something I'm not doing right, or is there another approach I could use to meet this requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `$watch` to watch for changes in your model.

E.g.

```
$scope.$watch("selectedCats", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    var catLength = newValue.length;        
    var valid = (catLength <= 3);
    $scope.myStoryForm.selectedCats.$setValidity("maxLength", valid);
});
```

This gets triggered every time that your "selectedCats" value changes as well as the first time that you initialise the value.

Comment: Yes, I tried $scope.watch and got the same result.  Nothing happened.  tested on other fields in same form and it works. It seems like the selection of values doesn't trigger anything through these approaches, using Anglaur Multiple Select. I can get it to do a validation check once the form is submitted, but its not a nice solution.